# Run function after logging using the logging module in python

Tags: python, logging

I want to increase a variable by 1 OR run a function that does that every time something is logged to `log` - `lognum` in my case.

```
lognum = 1
logger = logging.getLogger('module')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.FileHandler(filename='log', encoding='utf-8', mode='w')
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(f'----CHUNK {lognum}----\nLEVEL: %(levelname)s\nNAME:%(name)s\nMESSAGE:%(message)s\n----CHUNK {lognum}----\n'))
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

I can't add the code after the setFormatter- it just sets the formatter. I've read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) for logging, can't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either [`filters`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.filter) or the py3 [`setLogRecordFactory`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.setLogRecordFactory) & [`getLogRecordFactory`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.getLogRecordFactory) to add contextual information to your logs.

Here's a quick and dirty example:

```
import sys
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
COUNT = 1
FMT = """----CHUNK %(lognum)s----
LEVEL: %(levelname)s
NAME:%(name)s
MESSAGE:%(message)s
----CHUNK %(lognum)s----"""

def main():
    logger.info('hello, world')
    logger.warning('this is a warning log')
    logger.error('this is bad!')

def init_logger():
    log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
    formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt=FMT)
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    log.addHandler(handler)

    old_factory = logging.getLogRecordFactory()

    def record_factory(*args, **kwargs):
        global COUNT
        record = old_factory(*args, **kwargs)
        record.lognum = COUNT
        COUNT += 1
        return record

    logging.setLogRecordFactory(record_factory)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    init_logger()
    main()
```

and the output:

```
----CHUNK 1----
LEVEL: INFO
NAME:__main__
MESSAGE:hello, world
----CHUNK 1----
----CHUNK 2----
LEVEL: WARNING
NAME:__main__
MESSAGE:this is a warning log
----CHUNK 2----
----CHUNK 3----
LEVEL: ERROR
NAME:__main__
MESSAGE:this is bad!
----CHUNK 3----
```

and [here you can find](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-filters-to-impart-contextual-information) a similar example by using `filters`.

Answer (score 0):

An effective and quick solution to run certain functions only during debugging and logging is to use the [`getEffectiveLevel()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.getEffectiveLevel) method of the logger,

```
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr, level=logging.DEBUG) # turn on the logger
logr = logging.getLogger() # get the logger object

if logr.getEffectiveLevel() == 10: # if debugging is ON
    replace_it_with_your_function()
```

Where number 10 is the numeric value which [`getEffectiveLevel()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.getEffectiveLevel) function returns. The numeric values of other effective levels are given below,

[image]